# Is it correct to add an adjective after a preposition?

Tags: adjectives, prepositional-phrases, noun-phrases

Here is a sentence from an English magazine:

> With the weather still *on this side of chilly*, it might be better to stay in and nest ― especially when nursing a cold.

Why not write *on this side of chill?* Can we always add an adjective after a preposition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence from the magazine is informal, even a bit ambiguous, but it is correct insofar as it uses *chilly* rather than *chill*.  One might well say that *The weather is chilly* or *It's chilly outside*.  One might also say *There is a chill in the air*, but one would never say *The weather is chill.*

Therefore the word **chilly** is the correct one for describing weather in your magazine's sentence.

Answer (score 1):

A preposition is usually followed by a noun phrase. 'this side of chilly' is a noun phrase.